# C# How to create a class that stores string values from textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm relatively new in C# and in this website.

I'm currently trying to make this application that stores employees' data (e.g. name, surname, id number, salary) and shows the selected employee's data upon command.
My problem is that I do not know what kind of class to create and how to build it as well as how to call it each time I click the "save button" to create a new instance of that class which will save the data drawn from the Form's textboxes.

I have searched in forums and have managed to write this inside the Form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Employee newemployee = new Employee();

    {
        string fname = textBox1.Text;
        string sname = textBox2.Text;
        string id = textBox3.Text;
        string sal = textBox4.Text;

        label5.Text = fname;
        label6.Text = sname;
        label7.Text = id;
        label8.Text = sal;
    }
}
```

and this inside the class:

```
public class Employee {
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string sname { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string sal { get; set; }
}
```

but as a result ofcourse, the class is not used at all (obviously because its not completed) and labels are printed straight through the textboxes.

**Note: I put the labels there in order to test the class during the process.**

Comment: have a look at the presenter pattern.

Comment: Instead of saying:

    string fname = textBox1.Text;

Put:

newemployee.fname = textBox1.Text;

Comment: "the class is not used at all (obviously because its not completed)" not exactly. It is actually used. But your poroblem is that you declare new local variables when you use the `string` in front of it. This way you don't use the class properties. remove the `string` in front of all variables when you initialize `newemployee` and have a look at the result

Comment: What you've wrote, it's just creating new `newemployee` then opening scope and doing something, which is not related to your newly created `newemployee ` object.

Comment: Have a look at [Initialize Objects by Using an Object Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer)

Comment: And please make the property names start with uppercase.

Comment: Please mark an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class, you have already created string values, which will be created when you create the instance of your class:

```
Employee newemployee = new Employee();
```

This creates memory space for all the variables declared in your class

```
public class Employee 
{
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string sname { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string sal { get; set; }
}
```

What you are doing is then creating additional strings by saying:

```
string fname = textBox1.Text;
string sname = textBox2.Text;
string id = textBox3.Text;
string sal = textBox4.Text;
```

So to when you initialize the class it created the variables which you should use for that instance of the class. The following code represents the initializing of the class and using its variables from your example code:

```
Employee newemployee = new Employee();

newemployee.fname = textBox1.Text;
newemployee.sname = textBox2.Text;
newemployee.id = textBox3.Text;
newemployee.sal = textBox4.Text;

label5.Text = newemployee.fname;
label6.Text = newemployee.sname;
label7.Text = newemployee.id;
label8.Text = newemployee.sal;
```

Hope that helps and it explains where you went wrong.

Comment: why? is there a reason why the first line does not work and the second does?

Comment: You are creating a new string by saying string fname. Your class already stored memory for a string fname.

Comment: As what you're doing, you creating a string instead of using the string your class has already created

Comment: I don't create strings ;) it's not my post. I ask only annoying questions to help people to improve their posts :) This information that you've wrote in your comments belong into your answer. They will improve the quatlity of it

Comment: @MongZhu Thank you, was in a rush answering but hope it's up to standard now

Answer (score 1):

You would instantiate your class like this:

```
Employee newEmployee = new Employee()
    {
        fname = textBox1.Text,
        sname = textBox2.Text,
        id = textBox3.Text,
        sal = textBox4.Text
    };
```

and then write a method to save your Employee in a database/file which you call after instantiating in the click event.

Answer (score 1):

You're not initialising your class in your calling script, so it can't see it. I suggest having a read of the MS Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes

It has an example that does pretty much what you need it to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can create instance and from the class and set the properties

```
Employee newEmp = new Employee();
newEmp.fname = textBox1.Text;
newEmp.sname = textBox2.Text;
newEmp.id = textBox3.Text;
newEmp.sal = textBox4.Text;
```